# Sass/Css Can I set multiple classes in hover action?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to set some sibling classes in on `hover` action and I do it this way:

```
.div-inside-1:hover ~ .div-inside-tran-1{
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0%;
}
.div-inside-1:hover ~ .div-inside-tran-1::after{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}
```

Can I do it without copying and pasting the `.div-inside-1:hover`? One more thing is that how to set properties in  `::after` by hover in other class?
Thank you very much!

**Edited**:
Please refer to https://jsfiddle.net/k6ws0j9t/

Comment: Can you be more clear about your second question? Without any HTML and what class you need to hover on to add properties in the `::after`, we can't guess what you need.

Comment: @hhnn Did my solution below worked for you?

Comment: @Arkellys I am so sorry, please see the link above, thank you!
I would like to know if I can set the attribute in `::after` on the `hover` action in the parent class (`mybutton-thumb-des`).    Rather than set-up the `:hover::after` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do in Sass like this

```
.div-inside-1 {
  &:hover {
    ~ .div-inside-tran-1 {
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      opacity: 0%;

      &::after {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setting properties of `::after` pseudo code on hover of some else class like this

```
.class{
    &hover{
      .class2{
        &::after{
          content:'';
          background: none;//Your properties
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

> Remember this can be done only if relation is parent child class, you
>   cant target parent by child trough css for that you need `JavaScript`

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that the prefix of two children classes are the same, please refer to the link above. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what actually you want?

Comment: you can see that there is  `:hover ~ .mybutton-des{...};` and
   `:hover ~ .mybutton-border{...}`. Can I do something like `:hover{ ~.class1{...}, ~.class2{...} }`?

Comment: Yes you can! in your case both theses classes are child of single parent on which you hover.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers;)